# Maven: File does not get excluded from build

Tags: maven

I have a library maven module which has an application.conf file in /src/main/resources/ and I want to exclude it from the build in the pom of the module

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>application.conf</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

A maven module, which uses the above mentioned module, shall build a jar with all dependencies; I use the maven assembly plugin to build actually the jar.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--<descriptor>src/assembly.xml</descriptor>-->
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>                    
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The file application.conf is still there in the jar. What I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

do this :

```
 <exclude>**/application.conf</exclude>
```

Comment: you mean in <resources>  ? Unfortunately, this does not solve the issue

Comment: all is good, normally it should work, not forget clean : mvn clean package

Comment: I would recommend doing `mvn clean install` instead. Then you don't run the risk of the _assembly_ picking up an old version of the dependency. By the way, you are running the command from root pom, aren't you?